# Paypal chained payments and conditionally approved app

Tags: php, paypal, chained-payments

I developed a website which uses the Paypal chained payments. It works fine with the Sandbox but when I move to production the Paypal API says the user doesn't have permissions to use chained payments.

I requested the permissions needed by my website and it was 'conditionally approved', but as I learned in the documentation and internet forums, chained payments are considered advanced features and won't work with a conditionally approved app.

I've been waiting for two months for my application to be approved and I didn't even receive any notification from Paypal. Does it usually take that long? I was hoping it to be ready in a few weeks it's been months already, maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just call them up and ask whats the status, I doubt anyone here can do that for you :P